# Order a List<object> lexicographically using brute force

Tags: c#, lexicographic

That's my code...

```
string text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis nisl vitae dolor tempus iaculis at id augue. Nullam metus mauris, viverra vitae tristique sed, pulvinar ac nulla."

List<object> listCarac = new List<object>();
object aux = 0;

text.Replace(" ", "");

for (int i = 0; i < text.Count(); i++)
{
    listCarac.Add(text.Substring(i,1));
}

for (int x = 0; x < listCarac.Count(); x++)
{
    for (int y = x + 1; y < listCarac.Count(); y++)
    {
        if (listCarac[x] > listCarac[y]) // My problem is here
        {
            aux = listCarac[x];
            listCarac[x] = listCarac[y];
            listCarac[y] = aux;
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is how to compare lexicographically, i guess the if is comparing alphabetically.
Thanks.

Comment: Well let's start with what counts as "lexicographic" ordering if your list actually contained (say) a `FileStream` and a `Button`... (You might want to start with a `List<string>`. Also, note that your `text.Replace` method call is doing nothing useful, as you're ignoring the return value...)

Comment: You need to define the object to be IComparable, or at least check and cast to IComparable. Pretty much all c# base types have that, and it's used by pretty much all sorting.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile since there's no `>` operator for `object`. It looks like you want to sort the chars in a string? The simplest solution would be to use `text.OrderBy` in that case.

Comment: I can't use a list of strings, i need to do this with a generic list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list contains instances of type `object` which does not implement `IComparable` and thus you can´t call `instance1 < instance2`. However as you put only single characters into your list I guess you can use a `List<char>` instead or even simpler `string`  instead of a list.

Thus you can now call this:

```
listCarac = listCarac.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

Which will order your characters lexigraphically.

Furthermore when calling `string.Replace` the result is returned by the method as strings are immutable. So Within your first loop you use the original content of `text` instead of the replaced. Use this instead: `text = text.Replace(" ", "");`

EDIT: If - as you claim in your comments - you have to use a list of `object` and all the instances within this list implement `IComparable` (which `char` does) you can simply cast the instances to the interface before sorting:

```
var result = listCarac.OfType<IComparable>().OrderBy(x => x);
```

Comment: I can't use a list of char, i need to do this with a generic list.

Comment: Sorry, i have to use a list of objects. Can i just convert the character to Unicode and compare the values? If yes, how can i do this conversion?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know much about `object` but we do know about IComparable items.

I would suggest you changing the list to

```
var listCarac = new List<IComparable>();
```

And than using the interface method [CompareTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx)

```
int CompareTo(
    object obj
)
```

Which will change

```
if (listCarac[x] > listCarac[y])
```

To

```
if (listCarac[x].CompareTo(listCarac[y]) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take advantage of the SORT method provided for List. If necessary, you can provide a comparator to handle particular cases.

```
String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse quis nisl vitae dolor tempus iaculis at id augue. Nullam metus mauris, viverra vitae tristique sed, pulvinar ac nulla.";
text = text.Replace(" ", "");
List<char> demo = text.ToCharArray().ToList();
demo.Sort();
string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(demo.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray());
```